# Lightning: Getting a 401 when calling @AuraEnabled Apex method to do a REST call

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, chatter, rest, aura

Trying to write an Apex method that accesses Chatter REST api using this technique:
https://chintanblog.blogspot.com/2017/02/call-salesforce-rest-api-from-apex.html

This method is @AuraEnabled - so it can be called from a Lightning Component.

The problem is I'm getting a 401:

**System.CalloutException: [{"message":"This session is not valid for use with the REST API","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]**

```
String sfdcURL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm(); 
String restAPIURL = sfdcURL + '/services/data/v41.0/chatter/feed-elements';  

HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();  
httpRequest.setMethod('POST');   
httpRequest.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());        
httpRequest.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId()); 
httpRequest.setEndpoint(restAPIURL);  

httpRequest.setBody('test');

Http http = new Http();   
HttpResponse httpResponse = http.send(httpRequest);
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow up:

Using Named Credentials is fine - but it won't work in all cases. For instance - if I was to use Chatter, the identity used is the Named Credential authorized. This won't work.

Using a VF Page however, uses the current user's session. This seems to be what I need.

FOLLOW UP: 1-9-2019

I ran into this article which described exactly what I needed back then. It is a really good write up with great explanations, history and a references:

https://douglascayers.com/2018/09/10/calling-rest-api-from-lightning-components-without-named-credentials/

Kudos DOUGLAS C. AYERS

Answer (score 9):

The Session Id for Lightning is specifically restricted from most API calls. This means that you need to use a Named Credential to enable access to the APIs. This is outlined in [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apex_api_calls.htm#apex_api_calls).

> By security policy, sessions created by Lightning components aren’t enabled for API access. This prevents even your Apex code from making API calls to Salesforce. Using a named credential for specific API calls allows you to carefully and selectively bypass this security restriction.
>
> The restrictions on API-enabled sessions aren’t accidental. Carefully review any code that uses a named credential to ensure you’re not creating a vulnerability.

So, you need to create a Named Credential back to the Salesforce API, then use that Named Credential instead of using `UserInfo.getSessionId()`.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. Let me look at this Named Credential.

Comment: I created a Named Credential - but I want it to authenticate as the current user. Now I'm getting this error: 

**You don't have permission to view this data. Ask your administrator to set up authentication for the external data source.**

Note that I'm trying to access Chatter REST api - in the same org, through Lightning + APEX.

Answer (score 1):

[Winter 19](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_apex_streamline_api_calls.htm) on words we can make API calls to own SF org from @Aura Enabled Apex Methods with out using Remote site Settings/connected App

Comment: this is still not possible. I am getting the same invalide_session_id error in v47.0

Comment: @SagarThoriya can you post your issue with new Question, so it's easy to give solution for your Issue.

Comment: From the doc it is still not possible. Read last paragraph

Answer (score 0):

The solution: **Connected App and Named Credentials** can be followed in this tutorial [Calling Salesforce APIs From Lightning Components](https://eltoroit.herokuapp.com/Blog.app?page=ETLC_APIsFromApex)

There is also another option - which is to use a VF page. More information here: [How to Call Salesforce API from Lightning Component](https://sfdcpanther.wordpress.com/2018/02/05/how-to-call-salesforce-api-from-lightning-component/)

Answer (score 0):

I found the simplest solution - get the session id from apex page.
Here we go  :
Create visualforce page name SessionId.
Page content :

```
<apex:page contentType="text/plain">
    <apex:outputText >{!$Api.Session_ID}</apex:outputText>
</apex:page>
```

Get session id in the lightning component controller :

```
private static String getApexSessionId() {
    
    PageReference reportPage = Page.SessionId;
    if (Test.isRunningTest()) {
        sessionId =UserINfo.getSessionId();
    } else {
        sessionId = reportPage.getContent().toString();
    }
    return sessionId;  
}
```

Work like a charm!