# Can API access be limited to only via Apex classes?

Tags: lightning-web-components, rest-api, security, apexrest, session

We are building a product that offers two routes to the back-end data:

1. JSON calls to @RestResource Apex class APIs
2. LWC calls to @AuraEnabled Apex classes

Is there a profile setup that keeps these routes open but stops all other APIs from working e.g. the normal [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_rest_resources.htm) mechanism?

The reason to ask is that the security model we require is quite simple to implement via the Apex classes but would be much more challenging to impose via sharing rules.

(This for a Community.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In [Winter '18](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_rest_permission.htm&type=5&release=210), they added an ability to control access to Apex REST Services that is distinct from the *API Enabled* permission on profiles that provides access to the standard APIs.

This allows you to set up a profile that does not have access to the standard APIs, but gives you access to Apex REST Services. The user will also need access to the apex class itself. I do not believe you need to contact Salesforce for this setting to appear (*even though it says so in the Winter '18 release notes*), you should see it on the profile under *Administrative Permissions*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kris - looks promising. Any experience of where `@AuraEnabled` fits into this?

Comment: Ah, I missed that. I believe the profile should just need apex class permissions to the @aura enabled class?

Comment: More Googling says this critical update [Restrict Access to @AuraEnabled Apex Methods for Guest and Portal Users Based on User Profile (Critical Update)](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_lc_restrict_apex_guest_users.htm) brings being able to limit the AuraEnabled classes for Communities into play so making them similar to the RestResource classes.

Comment: I see comments like "The Session Id for Lightning is specifically restricted from most API calls" here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/218853/lightning-getting-a-401-when-calling-auraenabled-apex-method-to-do-a-rest-call so sounds like no "API Enabled" style access available there either.